# How do you hide a dropdown box using java script/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code to hide an essay question or open text.
I'd like to have the same effect but hide a drop down box.

In this example below if you select the "I will write in my choice below" the essay question will auto remove. I need to change this essay question to a drop down and I need the supporting Jquery to make the drop down dissaper if the write in choice is selected.

Please select your First Choice from the drop down or tell us that you will "Write In" or choice by selecting "I will "Write In" my choice below.
    ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
    ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***
    ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

Q. I will "Write In" my choice below.

```
jQuery(function($){
   $('input[type=checkbox]',$('#table1')).click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('textarea',$('#table1')).empty().hide();
     } else {$('textarea',$('#table1')).show();}
   });
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: no, it is for my job - I am not in IT. I am just trying to learn Jquery in 30 minutes or less

Comment: Mary, it would be really useful for us to see a HTML in an example. I'm a bit confused by your question. Here you can build your demo: http://jsbin.com or here: http://jsfiddle.net  BTW, you can hide an element doing: $('select#dropdown').hide();

Comment: do you have a way I could show you privately?

Comment: This is for an "employee survey" if you will. I have the survey built and can give you a link but I would prefer to send it to you via e-mail.

Comment: I don't think this is the place for this type of activity

Comment: Mary, can you try to be more specific? Or I'll write an answer based on guessing! :)

Comment: @MaryPlissey To get help on Stack Overflow, details need to be contained within your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/azowud/edit#javascript,html,live)*

HTML

```
  <p>Please select your First Choice from the drop down or tell us that you will "Write In" or choice by selecting "I will "Write In" my choice below.</p>
   
  <select id="choose_question">
    <option selected="selected">Choose a question</option>
    <option value="q1">Question 1</option>
    <option value="q2">Question 2</option>
    <option value="q3">Question 3</option>
    <option value="q4">Question 4</option>    
  </select>
  
  <br>
  
  <input id="ill_write" type="checkbox" /> I will write in my question.
  
  <br>
  
  <input id="my_question" type="text" value="" style="display:none; width:300px;"/>
```

jQuery

```
$('#choose_question').change(function(){  
  $('#my_question').fadeTo(50,0);
  $('input#ill_write').prop('checked', false);
});

$('#ill_write').change(function(){  
  $('#my_question').fadeTo(500,1); 
});
```